# SVN branching structure

Tags: svn, branch, branching-and-merging

I was exploring through the SVN branching patterns adopted by many projects. In my project, I want to have a set of release branch on the basis of iterations and a few feature branches depending on the complexity and time sensitiveness of the feature. But along with these I want each member to have a repository branch of their own where they can save their work but I don't want them to have the whole workspace as space is limited and I can't afford to provide each of them a working copy of the project. Now I want members to work on the release branch and commit their good work there but incomplete work to go to a certain place so that there is no code loss. What can do in such a scenario?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean when you say you can't affort to provide each developer a working copy.